Why are val_loss and val_val_sparse_categorical_crossentropy different if my metric is the same as the loss?
I'm compiling a keras model like so:
model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop", loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True), 
metrics=['sparse_categorical_crossentropy'])

history = model.fit(training_set, validation_data=val_set, epochs = 42)

As the model is training, it's outputing 4 different numbers:
loss: 0.5324
sparse_categorical_crossentropy: 1.3270
val_loss: 6.3679
val_sparse_categorical_crossentropy: 9.9764
When compiling, I think my metric is the same as the loss, so why is loss not equal to sparse_categorical_crossentropy and val_loss not equal to  val_sparse_categorical_crossentropy? Is one of them normalized? My data is a tensorflow dataset that has already been batched.

probably because from_logits=False is the default.

The reason why are you getting different results when you use same loss
function and metrics is due to (from_logits = True) in your loss function.If
you use activation function in the last layer you will get the same values
for loss and metrics .i have execute code with different cases please refer
to this gist
